# Search result will display on responsive popup

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax, popup

I fetched record from mysql database when i enter any keyword in search box.
up to this everything run properly and also shows result of that particular keyword. My query is the fetched result will shows just below the search box instead of that i should show results on popup and the popup should be responsive also.
plz suggest me,
Below is the code

**index.php**

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd"><html lang="pt" dir="ltr"><head><link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap-3.3.5-dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="font-awesome-4.3.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<!-- JQUERY FROM GOOGLE API -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
  $(function() {
    $("#lets_search").bind('submit',function() {
      var value = $('#str').val();
       $.post('db_query.php',{value:value}, function(data){
         $("#search_results").html(data);
       });
       return false;
    });
  });
</script></head>  <body>

<div style="text-align:center;">
  <form id="lets_search" action="" >
    Search:<input type="text" name="str" id="str">
    <input type="submit" value="send" name="send" id="send">
  </form>
  <div id="search_results"></div>
</div></body></html>
```

**db_query.php**

```
<?php $con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root", "","u871197953_shope") or die("Error connecting to database: ".mysql_error()); mysqli_select_db($con,"u871197953_shope") or die(mysql_error()); $query = mysqli_query($con,"select feed_product_image,feed_product_name,price,deeplink,image from wp_pc_products_merchants e,wp_pc_products w where e.slug=w.id_merchant and feed_product_name LIKE '%".$_POST['value']."%' LIMIT 20");   if(mysqli_num_rows($query) > 0)
    {
    ?>
    <div class="input-group col-sm-10  modal-box"  id="popup" title="Search Results" style="text-align:center;margin-top:10px;">
          <table class="table table-hover" style="text-align:center;">
            <thead>
                 <tr bgcolor="#1E90FF" >
                          <th>Products</th>
                          <th style="text-align:center;">Details</th>
                          <th>Retailers</th>
                          <th>Price</th>
                          <th>Buy</th>
                 </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
            <?php 
            while($results = mysqli_fetch_array($query))
            { ?>
                  <tr>
                     <td><img src = "<?php  echo $results['feed_product_image'];  ?>"  style="object-fit:contain;height:60px;width:80px;" /></td>
                     <td><?php  echo "<p style='font-size:12px;'>".$results['feed_product_name']. "</p>" ; ?></td>
                     <td><img src = "<?php  echo $results['image'];  ?>"  style="background-size:contain;height:30px;width:100px;"  /></td>
                     <td><?php echo '<i class="fa fa-inr">&nbsp;'.$results['price']. '</i>'.".00" ;   ?></td>
                     <td><a href="<?php  echo $results['deeplink'];  ?>" style="background-color:#ff8c21;" class="btn btn-warning btn-sm">Buy now</a></td>
                 </tr>
            <?php 
            }
            ?>
            </tbody>
          </table>
        <?php
    }
    else
    { // if there is no matching rows do following
        echo "No results found...";
    } ?>
```

Comment: there are tons of popup scripts out there like http://lab.veno.it/venobox/ or just build your own

Comment: Why are you loading multiple `JQuery` `<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>` and `<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>`

Comment: Actually my motive is to show result in popup that's why i am using above jquery links....and also use $("#search_results").dialog(); instead of $("#search_results").html(data); But it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

By default bootstrap popup/modal window is responsive. Dont worry about that.

Add modal window html codes in yor page.

```
<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Modal title</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        ...
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

After loading the result as add the result in model body

> $('#myModal .modal-body').html(data);

Then trigger model using:

> $('#myModal').modal(options);

```
- Use standard bootstrap options in the modal function.
```

Comment: Thanks for valuable reply.

Comment: I little bit understand the above bootstrap model, but how and where actually put it in my code and how to trigger that model....i really confusing   plz explain in details.....once again thanks for ur co-operation.

Comment: Add the modal inside your html. By default the modal will be invisible. Then change your ajax code as shown below:

`$.post('db_query.php',{value:value}, function(data){
 $('#myModal .modal-body').html(data);
 $('#myModal').modal('show');
});`

Comment: It's work fine, In this case how can i add both these pages in wordpress widgets area, I have already installed php-code-widget plugin to support php in widgets only it could not be run properly....thanks for your valuable support.

Comment: Just paste the content inside the <body> tag in index.php. Remember your theme should have boostrap css and jquery files. If not you have to add it separately. Upload db_query.php file to home directory in the host.